# set cookie if self.location.href!=top.location.href

Tags: javascript, cookies, setcookie

I need to set up a cookie only if the site is on an iframe, however for some reason I can't make it happen.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (self.location.href!=top.location.href) {
        document.cookie = "oniframe=yes;max-age=" + 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
    } 
</script>
```

While browsing the site on an iframe (on other site) I can't find the cookie.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks Daniel

Comment: Add some debug code such as `alert()` to see if your code inside the `if` body is actually executed.

Comment: Since you mention `iframe` you may also want to add a longer explanation of whther your code runs inside/outside the iframe, as well as examples of the domain names used for the main document and the iframe, since that dictate a whole lot of security policies in the browser.

Comment: I don't see how that will help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect if your site is being loaded in an iframe, you can compare the `self` and `top` objects directly, e.g:

```
if (self === top)

    //Not loaded in iframe

else

    //Loaded in iframe
```